# YouTube API V3 Comment Threads doesn't work with access Token

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to call the following url with my access token which is for getting comments from a video but it doesn't seem to work and gives me a `Insufficient Permissions Error`.

Here's the URL I try to call-

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=1&videoId=tdUX3ypDVwI&access_token={myAccessToken}`

but it sends me the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Insufficient Permission"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
  }
}
```

Apparently, It doesn't make sense to me? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following scope :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
```